# Wrong and ignored language to be translated

Tags: i18n-l10n

My website is by default in French and I need to get an English version.

**Prob n°1** : I've got this kind of Exposed filter (exported in a block), everything in it is translated excepted "Tri" (sort) and "Appliquer" (apply) which stay in french.

[image]

Here, you can see all modules about languages/i18n (add i18n, i18n_block)

[image]

In my exposed filter settings (in FR) :

[image]

In the view, translate view > English > traduire > and I wrote this

[image]

In Config > Regional > Translate I found what I wrote correctly

[image]

**Answer n°1** : Why my exposed filter labels can't be translated ?

**Answer n°2** : Another thing, it's maybe common but I found this strange, when I write a sentence in `t()` function, it must be in english and not in my site language else I get

[image]

Is it normal to write in english in `t()` function even if the site language is not ?

Thanks in advance for helps. I'm listening some tricks, advices and good practice about languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to select source/default language from `admin/config/regional/language`.

After you need to import .po file of English or your selected import other import languages **(https://localize.drupal.org/translate/languages/en)**.

Now you will able to translate your term from `Config > Regional > Translate`. and those are visible according to your language.

Comment: French was still selected and put to default, and English enabled. I just import the file you said but nothing change about my exposed filters labels.

Comment: did you import .po file? I have given you a link where you can download english.po file. and import it at **admin/config/regional/translate/import**

Comment: check this one https://i.stack.imgur.com/rt55v.jpg and enable it

Comment: Yes, I imported .po file. And my config is the same than yours (about your screen). In Config>Regional>Translate, all is good as earlier but exposed filters don't change... Something about http://imgur.com/1bONxM1 ?

Comment: You need to go with the **core** and refresh language then again check translation is stay, if not then add again translate string after view front page.

Comment: You can suggest me the differents step, like to refresh ? When I check Core, nothing is translated from Views and in Regional>Translate, I get my french string which could be translate in french.

Comment: It's really, really boring. Everything could be translated excepted my exposed filters. One more put I missed, it's a Better Exposed Filters... Maybe... I'll try something test with common filter.

Comment: Ok ok. It works well with labels from common Exposed filters.

Comment: Last time you can try this go /admin/structure/views/settings/advanced there in the localization options choose 'core'. Then all strings in views (Exposed filters labels included) become translatable via the string override module. Seems like Internationalization Views changes that setting by default. Reverting it makes everything work as it should

Comment: Ok, it seems to be clean now :) Thanks for your time @KrishaWeb